# Xubuntu strange behaviour panel-indicator and panel-notification applet

Tags: indicator, xfce, xfce-panel

I am running Xubuntu 14.04 32bit on a Lenovo X200 and got some strange behavior from the `panel-indicator` and `panel-notification` applets.

Both show `blueman` and I got multiple keyboard layout setting. So I got 3 icons for the keyboard, one would be enough. Also I lost my network icon so no way of using the WiFi now.

But if I log into the guest account, I do have the network icon so don't know what's wrong there, when I try to restart the network service it fail!

Can it be some broken package? It is a clean and fresh install. Should I switch to the 64bit version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps there is an answer to get the network icon back:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-panel/+bug/1302462

http://xubuntugeek.blogspot.de/2013/04/solved-network-icon-missing-from-xfces.html