# Extra items in panel after installing xubuntu over ubuntu

Tags: unity, xubuntu, indicator, panel

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Thinkpad T60 and found out that Unity is too slow. So, I did

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

When I log into an Xubuntu session, the panel has a ton of junk from the Unity interface (a Power menu with a non-working logout button, an extra language indicator that does not work, an extra clock).

[image: extra junk in the panel]

How can I get rid of them, ideally without breaking my ability to log into Unity?

**EDIT:** I found other questions that ask about the same problems. They do not seem to have any useful answers:

[Xubuntu strange behaviour panel-indicator and panel-notification applet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457231/)

[Xfce top panel indicator problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/447637/)

Comment: Can you remove it in the panel properties, items tab (description here http://www.linuceum.com/Distros/osDesktopConfigXfce.php) ?

Comment: This [link](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/alternative) worked well for me. It removes most of the slower features of 14.04.

Answer (score 2):

That is the new XUbuntu panel plugin for the new Unity indicator (`libindicator` & `libappindicator`).

1. Right click on the panel → panel → Panel Preferences... → Items tab

   Then select `Indicator Plugin`

   [image]
2. Either you remove it completely from panel using (-) button, or as I recommend customizing it.

   - Click (gear) button
   - Check "Hide indicators by default"
   - Check "Application Indicators" to be "Visible"

   Why? because some application uses only `libappindicator` method to show their status icon. You may not want to miss them.

   [image]

[image]